# PASS Password store: Environment variable has no effect on password store location

Tags: environment-variables, password, password-store

I have been using pass for some time to store passwords, but now I want to move my password store from the default location. According to the man page, it is enough to set `PASSWORD_STORE_DIR` variable to the desired path to override the default one, however in my case this has no effect.
After I move the `.password-store` folder to a new location and set the environment variable, executing the command `pass` results in "Error: password store is empty. Try "pass init".". Even if simply renaming the `.password-store` inside home directory:

```
$ cd
$ mv .password-store .pass
$ PASSWORD_STORE_DIR=/home/bakhtin/.pass #bakhtin is the user name
$ pass
Error: password store is empty. Try "pass init".
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be? I made sure the are no spelling errors in the variable's name and such.

Comment: Is the variable `PASSWORD_STORE_DIR` exported?

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I am still new to the logic of environment variables, so forgot that exporting is a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the variable and its value need to be accessed by `pass`, a process started from the shell and running separately from it, the variable needs to be an environment variable. Environment variables are inherited by child processes, but other shell variables are not inherited.

In your case, you have simply forgotten to use `export` on the `PASSWORD_STORE_DIR` variable to tag it as an environment variable.

```bash
export PASSWORD_STORE_DIR=~bakhtin/.pass
```

You may also use just `export PASSWORD_STORE_DIR` to mark the variable as an environment variable if you have already assigned a value to it.

Another way to pass the variable into the environment of `pass` without even creating it as a shell variable in the invoking shell is to write the assignment in front of the invocation of `pass`:

```bash
PASSWORD_STORE_DIR=~bakhtin/.pass pass
```

This sets the variable's value for the `pass` process but does not create a variable in the current shell.